# DBT:Executing macros as standalone doesn't run anything

Tags: dbt

The requirement is to have the macro executed so that it loops through each and inserts data
I cannot create a model due to the huge number of columns

I have created macros below  and run dbt command as

`dbt run-operation generate_insert_sql`

But it just ran and nothing got executed

-- generate_insert_sql

```
 {% set c = ["COL_A", "COL_B", "COL_C", "COL_D", "COL_E"] %}

{% for c1 in c %}
    {% for c2 in c if c2 != c1 %}
        {{ generate_insert_sql(c1, c2) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% macro generate_insert_sql(c1, c2) %}
    INSERT INTO TABLE_A (
        cols,aggr_cols
    )
    SELECT cols, aggr_cols
      FROM TABL_2
    ) as a
    WHERE c1_type = '{{ c1 }}' AND c2_type = '{{ c2 }}'
    GROUP BY ALL;
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbt macros don't inherently run SQL code. You can use the built-in [`run_query`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) macro, or a [`statement`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/statement-blocks) block to actually run your SQL code.